# Are brass and copper utensils safe for humans to eat from?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, corrosion, chemistry

In my research over the internet everyone is telling that brass is not safe but still there are solenoid valves, joints, and piping made of brass used in everything like coffee machines, water dispensers etc.

Comment: many pans for making jam are copper....

Comment: Are they safe? Because according to Google copper and brass isn't.

Comment: The sites I have looked at don't say "don't" but they do suggest that food should not be left in the copper pans to cool down... see https://www.gourmet-web.com/Interesting-facts-about-copper-pots-and-copper-cookware  and https://www.livestrong.com/article/430746-is-it-safe-to-cook-in-copper-pots/

Comment: This site is also suggesting that copper is not good for consumption it is poisonous if used inside the pan.

Comment: which site.....?

Comment: Perhaps you should avoid the stainless steel ones as well: http://pubmedcentralcanada.ca/pmcc/articles/PMC4284091/

Comment: and whisky is distilled in copper stills - should that be banned on safety grounds?

Comment: I don't know but i am not here to judge or regulate anything but to clear my confusion about it.

Comment: Then read the links and think about time, contact and concentration levels...

Comment: Prior to the recent widespread use of PVC tubes & pipes, copper pipes where used for domestic water supply plumbing. I also have a vague recollection of some domestic hot water heaters being made of copper. And I can also recall my final year high school chemistry teacher (a long time ago) telling the class not to drink water from a domestic hot water heater because of the metal content of the water - ie don't make cups of coffee or tea with such water.

Comment: Typical USA house construction is copper supply piping and plastic waste piping.

Comment: @Fred that advice has more to do with making a good-tasting cup of tea than any potential toxicity.  Starting w/ cold water not only may reduce metal content but also keeps more oxygen (air, in general) in the water, which is believed to enhance flavor.

Comment: Certain brass alloys are subject to selective leaching where zinc is removed from the alloy by a small scale galvaning corrosion in chlorinated water. All brass alloys used in modern plumbing fittings should be made from DeZincification Resistant (DZR) brass which will not corrode this way.

Answer (score 2):

It always depends on the concentration and where you place the copper within the human body.

In my opinion, the most interesting example are implants which are coated with copper and implanted within the human body. The idea behind this is, that copper is toxic at very low concentrations for bacteria, and the toxic concentration for human cells is slightly higher. If you hit the window between these two concentrations, you can prevent bacteria from settling down on your implant.

Furthermore, the human body needs copper. The recommendations about the daily intake differ. Some studies in the US have shown that the general copper intake in the USA is too high, others showed that it's too low ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_in_health)).

Some more information are provided by WHO ([WHO - copper](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/chemicals/copper.pdf)).

During designing a product, it gets more complex since the amount of released copper is influenced by complex corrosion processes which highly depend on the medium, time, etc. I think e.g. copper pans are coated most often ([Copper pans](http://www.nytimes.com/health/guides/nutrition/cooking-utensils-and-nutrition/overview.html)) to prevent copper from entering your body.